# Background color CSS not working in safari but working fine in Chrome, Firefox

Tags: html, css, safari

I have made a website in which i am applying white background color(#FFF )  to my panels(a div) to add some transparency effect. This works very fine in chrome & firefox . But doesn't work in Safari. What should i do to create the same effect in safari.

```
.panel{
    position:relative;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background:#FFF;
    bgcolor:#FFF;
    #safari { background-color:#FFF }
}
```

I have tried all versions of background color(bgcolor, background-color etc) & also tried the hack

```
#safari{
    background-color:#FFF
}
```

but none worked. please help. 
Also the Link tags not working in IE only but working perfectly in other browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A white background does not add any transparency.

You can try the following, which should work in all browsers:

```
.my-class {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255); // White background for old browsers
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); // White background, 50% transparency for more modern browsers. Will be ignored by old browsers
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/safari-not-displaying-background-colour-correctly/) suggests this CSS hack:

```
# @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #safari { background-color:#FFF }
}
```

Comment: This works upto safari 5 versions but not working with safari 8.0 versions :(

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   _::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .panel {
     background-color:#FFF
  }
```

Edited: this works for safari 7.1+ (in your case, 8.0)

Comment: This works upto safari 5 versions but not working with safari 8.0 versions :(

Answer (score 0):

If it is showing bit difference with background-color, just try this -

```
#safari {
background-color: #fff;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add to your class

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```