# Embedded CSS not working with TextEdit on Mac

Tags: html, css, macos, textedit

I am very, very new, so please pardon my ignorance.
I was away (thus using PC's) and have learnt to use embedded css and had my practice website going ok, then I came home to face my Mac.

(I have not learnt to use a separate CSS, because that was hard to do on borrowed computers so I only know embedded and in-line CSS)

No matter what I do (the file was already formatted to be plain text, saved as html), I cannot get any CSS property "linked" to my html.  The html codes are showing, but the CSS seems completely lost.  I took a screen shot of the very simple example.  The right part is the what shows on the browser.  Can you please enlighten me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome, @turtlemeng Take a look at this when you have time: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you look at your developer console(google it) and see if there are any errors? This quotes look suspicious: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/53tub98j

Comment: To clarify what sheriffderek said - the quotes in <style type ="text/css"> look like they're special characters rather than plain quotes.That is they're ” instead of ". I think your tag can just be `<style>` anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much!  So far I have discovered (1) when I removed the quotes (I do not understand what "instead of" means yet.  But I just changed the tag to <style>, it worked! 
I'm not sure why.  I got this "style type="text/css" from the "Dummies Coding All-in-One", book.  As a newbie, I thought that was the standard language.  (2) I brought my website back by changing it from Unicode to Western Roman (whatever)!  Something good....

Answer (score 0):

Did you try other browsers?
There are some similar issues in this page [css not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530655/background-color-css-not-working-in-safari-but-working-fine-in-chrome-firefox).

After you try other browsers with the newest version, you can locate the problem. If other browsers also don't work, the problem might arise from your code.