# <a> tag background-color CSS not working in safari

Tags: html, css

I have the following link:

```
<a style="background-color: rgba(222, 82, 70, 0.85)" 
   id="provider-url" href="{% provider_login_url 'google' next='profile' %}" 
   class="btn btn-xs btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit">Google</a>
```

The color is showing up in chrome but not in Safari. I tried setting `z-index:1`, also tried setting `hexadecimal` values instead of `rgba` but also didn't work. Any ideas?

Edit: I checked and I am not cached

Comment: First check if you are cached

Comment: I did, and I am not cached

Comment: see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530655/background-color-css-not-working-in-safari-but-working-fine-in-chrome-firefox

Comment: That doesnt solve my problem unfortunately

Comment: are any of these classes overriding background-color: `btn btn-xs btn-block text-uppercase`?

Comment: @KetZoomer None of them. I tried removing them all and the color still doesn`t change. And I'm sure I'm not cached because when I change something else I can see the changes

Comment: does this element have a background color: `<a style="background-color: rgba(222, 82, 70, 0.85)">Google</a>`?

Comment: It does. I also tried setting `background` instead of `background-color` but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping a div and background-color to it around the hyperlink:

```
<div style="background-color: rgba(222, 82, 70, 0.85)" >
   <a id="provider-url" href="{% provider_login_url 'google' next='profile'  %}" 
      class="btn btn-xs btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit">Google</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I alredy tried this. It creates the following: https://ibb.co/2SyzGR2

Comment: If I use a button it works, but I need an `<a>` tag

Comment: @NicolasAgustin i'm stumped

Answer (score 0):

Remove `type="submit"` from the `a` tag

https://codepen.io/jeanno-the-sasster/pen/RwyZwgw