# Background color css not working in safari

Tags: css, safari

[image: show background color not working]

As Image on top, the background was silver in safari. But it is working fine on other browser (chrome & firefox)

Here is the code

**HTML:**

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Pesan a Sekarang</a>
```

**CSS:**

[image: css1]

I have already try with `rgba` and `rgb`, but it's still not working.

[image: rgba rgb safari]

so is this a bug from safari or what?
because I already read [Background color CSS not working in safari but working fine in Chrome, Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530655/background-color-css-not-working-in-safari-but-working-fine-in-chrome-firefox) and still not working

```
background-color: #e5131d!important;
border-color: #e5131d!important;
```

Here is the CSS

```
background-color: #e5131d!important;border-color: #e5131d!important;
```

Comment: Please provide your code not image of your code

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example will help you provide what we need to help you. In particular please provide the relevant HTML as well as the CSS and put the whole thing in a snippet so we can easily try it.

Comment: @Sfili_81 i just update the Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="#">{!! __('landingpage.button.details') !!}</a>
```

the problem was i use a tag element with attr type button

then i change into like this

```
<a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">text</button></a>
```

it works for me on safari

Comment: After searching for hours, this was the answer we where looking for! Thank you, you made my monday!
'The type='button' on the a tag was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using background:#e5131d instead. You might have the silver one set using background, which may overwrite background-color

You can also use the parent elements class before as a workaround

.parent .btn-danger{background:#e5131d}

Avoid !important